# Extract rows from a table based on another table in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I have a big table that has lots of rows and I want to extract some of them.
This is part of the table (bigtable_het.txt):

```
chr1    12064875    12064863    12064875    1   C   C   A
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    187445985   187445984   187445996   1   C   C   A
chr1    207155658   207155646   207155658   1   C   G   C
chr1    211828738   211828726   211828738   1   C   C   A
chr1    30180076    30180075    30180087    1   C   C   A
chr1    41898581    41898569    41898581    1   C   C   A
```

I want to extract the rows based on this list (list_only.lst):

```
1   C   G
1   G   C
3   A   G
3   G   A
4   A   G
4   C   G
4   G   A
4   G   C
5   A   C
5   C   A
```

If 5th, 7th and 8th columns of the bigtable_het.txt match with 1st, 2nd and 3rd column of the list_only.lst respectively, print those rows of the bigtable_het.txt as separate files and name them as the rows of the list_only.lst file (for example: only_1CG.txt, only_4AG.txt and so on.)

Both of the files are tab delimited.

Expected output:

for example the file only_1CG.txt will be like that:

```
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
```

I tried this:

```
 for i in $(cut -f 5 list_only.lst); do for j in $(cut -f 7 list_only.lst); do for k in $(cut -f k list_only.lst);do awk '{ if ($5==$i && $7==$j && $8==$k) print $0}' bigtable_het.txt; done; done; done
```

but it didn't give any output.

What should I edit in this script?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: [edit] your question to add the expected output given the sample input you provided so we can best help you. We can't test a potential solution with only input, we need to also know the expected output so we know if the solution is working or not.

Comment: @Dr... - can you ever have multiple chars in those key columns? For example could you have a situation where `AA` or `AC` or `AG` or some other pair of letters appears in the 7th or 8th column?

Comment: By the way, when you say `row` in your question in `If 5th, 7th and 8th rows of the bigtable_het.txt match with 1st, 2nd and 3rd row` and `name them as the rows of the list_only.lst file`, I assume you meant to say `column` instead of `row`, but when you say `print those rows of the bigtable_het.txt` I assume you really did mean `rows` - if that's correct then please fix the former usage of `row` to change it to `column`, if not then please clarify what you're trying to do - adding the expected output will help.

Comment: how big (MBytes) is `bigtable_het.txt`? is is pre-sorted and if so, by which column(s)? what's the expected max number of distinct values in the 1st column of `list_only.lst`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution using awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3]; next} ($5,$7,$8) in a {print $0 > ("only_" $5 $7 $8 ".txt")}' list_only.lst bigtable_het.txt

cat only_1CG.txt
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G

cat only_1GC.txt
chr1    207155658   207155646   207155658   1   C   G   C
```

---

Depending on the size of your files and your version of awk, you may need to close the files that are being created after they have been filled with the matching rows, or the command may fail with a 'too many files open' error, e.g.

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
    a[$1 $2 $3]
    next
}

{
    key = $5 $7 $8
    out = "only_" key ".txt"
}

out != prev {
    close(prev)
}

key in a {
    print > out
    prev = key
}' list_only.lst bigtable_het.txt

cat only_1CG.txt
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G
chr1    145293490   145293478   145293490   1   C   C   G

cat only_1GC.txt
chr1    207155658   207155646   207155658   1   C   G   C
```

Comment: Not a huge deal but just an alternative to consider - rather than duplicating the 2nd file key field numbers in `out = "only_" $5 $7 $8 ".txt"` and `($5, $7, $8) in a`, if you do `a[$1 $2 $3]` ... `key = $5 $7 $8; out = "out_" key ".txt"` ... `key in a` ... `prev = key` or similar then if you have to change which fields make up the key in the 2nd file you only have to change it in one place, reducing the chance of bugs. Normally I wouldn't recommend not having a separator between the key fields but the OPs output file names require each field to only have 1 char anyway so in this case it works

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton-SOstopbullying - I always appreciate your suggestions / improvements - I'll edit my answer :)